# How to get url parameter in model

Tags: magento2, url, model

How to get url parameter : at this file
app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/ResourceModel/Module/Grid/Collection.php

My Url is like this
http://192.168.2.215/mtheme/admin/vendor_module/index/details/id/1/

i want to get ID in the collection.php
how to achieve same,
thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**With objectManager**

```
$urlInterface = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Framework\UrlInterface');
$urlInterface->getCurrentUrl();
```

**With Factory Method**

```
protected $_urlInterface;

protected $request;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlInterface,
     \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
    ...
) {
    $this->_urlInterface = $urlInterface;
    $this->request       = $request;
}

public function getUrlInterfaceData()
{
    echo $this->_urlInterface->getCurrentUrl();

    echo $this->_urlInterface->getUrl();

    echo $this->_urlInterface->getUrl('test/test2');

    echo $this->_urlInterface->getBaseUrl();

    echo $this->request->getParam('id'); //current url id parameter value
}
```

I hope it help..!!!

Comment: i am trying to get it in model

Comment: @AdarshShukla have you try above code ?

Comment: will  echo $this->request->getParam('id');  work in resoursemodel/grid/collection

Comment: i am getting this error on admin panel wile using request->getParam('id'); in  app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/ResourceModel/Module/Grid/Collection.php                error is as following:- Missing required argument $model of Katalyst\Rfq\Model\ResourceModel\Rfqitems\Grid\Collection.

Comment: @AdarshShukla  add you code here.

Comment: @AdarshShukla okay.  Happy Coding :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86102/discussion-between-adarsh-shukla-and-balwant).

Comment: don`t use object manager in this case. its bad approach